# Ending a smarty foreach loop with 'and'

Tags: php, foreach, smarty

I’m pulling a list of names and dates out of an array that I would like to render as a natural language sentence, with the penultimate item followed by 'and', then the last item.

Here’s my code:

```
<p>In the past, we&rsquo;ve interviewed the likes of {foreach from=$interviewees key=k item=v name=people}
<a href="https://www.example.com/interviews/{$v}.html">{$k}</a
{if $smarty.foreach.people.last}. {else},{/if} {foreachelse}{/foreach}
```

where key is the person’s name, item is the url in the form of a date (201509). This outputs a nice comma separated list, but how do I insert a natural looking and to finish the list?

I’m hoping for the following output:

```
<p>In the past, we&rsquo;ve interviewed the likes of 
<a href="https://www.example.com/interviews/201405.html">Forename Surname</a>,  
<a href="https://www.example.com/interviews/201408.html">Forename Surname</a>,  
<a href="https://www.example.com/interviews/201403.html">Forename Surname</a> 
and  <a href="https://www.example.com/interviews/201312.html">Forename Surname</a>.
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<p>In the past, we&rsquo;ve interviewed the likes of {foreach     
from=$interviewees key=k item=v name=people}
{if $smarty.foreach.people.last} and {/if}
<a href="https://www.example.com/interviews/{$v}.html">{$k}</a>
{if $smarty.foreach.people.last}.{else}
   {if $smarty.foreach.people.iteration+1!=$smarty.foreach.people.total},{/if}  
{/if} {foreachelse}{/foreach}
```

Comment: That’s nearly it; I’m getting: “forename surname, forename surname, and forename surname”. Ideally we wouldn’t end up with an oxford comma before the 'and'…